# DependencyInjection for EventSubscribers in Symfony 2.7

Tags: symfony, events, dependency-injection

I am doing some file operations in S3 and need to perform a few actions after a temporary file has been successfully copied following an API request. For example, update the filesize stored in the DB.

I'd like to dispatch an event in the cases where this action needs to occur but any subscriber is going to need a few services like the filesystem and an entity manager and I cannot figure out how to inject services into the EventSubscriber since it needs to be created and added to the EventDispatcher as a subscriber in a class that is not aware of the filesystem or doctrine, or the container.

I've attempted to use the ContainerAwareEventDispatcher. Here's my event being dispatched in that way:

```
class PendingFile implements SourceFile
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @var PendingFileService
     */
    private $pendingFileService;

    /**
     * @param string $filename
     * @param PendingFileService $pendingFileService
     */
    public function __construct($filename, PendingFileService $pendingFileService)
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
        $this->pendingFileService = $pendingFileService;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $targetFilename
     * @param Media $media
     */
    public function process($targetFilename, Media $media)
    {
        $this->pendingFileService->copyFile($this->filename, $targetFilename);

        $event = new PendingFileCopyEvent($media);
        $eventDispatcher = new ContainerAwareEventDispatcher(new ContainerBuilder());
        $eventDispatcher->addSubscriberService(
            'acme.media.event_subscriber.pending_file_copy',
            'Acme\MediaBundle\EventSubscriber\PendingFileCopySubscriber'
        );
        $eventDispatcher->dispatch(PendingFileCopyEvent::EVENT_NAME, $event);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this container is empty and does not recognise my service. I can't inject these services into the entity itself. And if I could, why would I use an event subscriber anyway...

**Question:** How can I properly build my subscriber as a service with the dependencies it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should only use one instance of an event dispatcher. Symfony has a `@event_dispatcher` service. You should use it instead of instantiate a new one. So in your `PendingFile` Class, add a `EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher` in your constructor, then just dispatch an event like you do.

For the subscriber, you need to create the class, then declare it as a service with a tag `kernel.event_subscriber` like [explained in the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) to automatically register the event subscriber in the event dispatcher (so you can removed the `addSubscriberService` line of your code).

And Voila!

Comment: The issue is that I'm creating this class that does the copying from within a few places and in different use cases - it implements a source file and I only need to carry this action out for this type of source file. So I would need to inject the dispatcher into those, as well as this one and it starts to get a bit spaghetti?

Comment: Ooh - hang on. Ok I've moved the creation of this `SourceFile` to a factory method so I can inject different things to different types easily...